# Remove top margin from cover page of PDF generated using TuesPechkin

Tags: c#, tuespechkin

I am using TuesPechkIn to convert my html to PDF. I am setting the configuration as follows:

My question is, can I remove the top margin from the first page of the PDF only? (Basically its the cover page which includes a banner image). Is there any way to implement this.

```
        var document = new HtmlToPdfDocument
        {
            GlobalSettings =
            {
                DocumentTitle = "My Report",
                PaperSize = PaperKind.A4, 
                Margins =
                {
                    Top = 1.25, //Need to make it as 0 for the first page
                    Left = 0.00,
                    Right = 0.00,
                    Bottom = 1.25,
                    Unit = TuesPechkin.Unit.Centimeters
                },
                PageOffset = 2
            },
            Objects =
            {
                new ObjectSettings
                {
                    HtmlText = htmlText,
                    FooterSettings = footerSettings
                }
            }
        };

        return converter.Convert(document);
```

Answer (score 0):

A work around would be to remove that image in JavaScript. I was having the same issue on an element in the last bottom page an basically what I did was:

```
var element = document.getElementById("someID");
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

put that code when the window loads and add it to your `htmlText`, it will remove the element for you before it generates the PDF. 
To do this you need to enable js by simply adding to your `Objects` :

```
WebSettings =
                    {
                        EnableJavascript = true
                    }
```

Hope it helps you :)